# Add inrush current limiter to board for USB compliance

Tags: usb, inrush-current

I have no experience with current inrush limiter designs.

I have to design a simple prototype in which I have to adapt a USB port to be USB compliant but instead of 5 V to 3.3 V (nothing else changes) and add an inrush current limiter (see simplified block diagrams).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV2EJ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have only been provided with this information:

- Operating Power Mode: 430 mA (3.3 V USB Full Speed).
- Max. Inrush Current: 500 mA.

Taking into account my total ignorance, could a current-limiter power switch, with soft-start, work as an inrush current limiter? Such as [this one for example](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP22815-615.pdf%5D%5B1%5D).

If so, should the current limiter be adjusted to a value little over 430 mA and below 500 mA?

Thanks.

Comment: it could. It's questionable what you need the separate inrush current liming for – if you don't overdimension the input capacitor on the LDO (which your schematic is missing, by the way), you should be able to work without, if the LDO has overcurrent protection (it probably has). Also note that you don't strictly need an LDO – the > 1.5V difference between in- and output suggest a non-Low-DropOut regulator might do. Also note that you might not want to use a linear regulator at all – during 430 mA operation, your linear regulator has to dissipate 730 mA of waste heat.

Comment: To add to what @MarcusMüller said, to be USB compliant, can you even blindly draw 430mA without negotiating over USB first that you need more than 100mA, and continue only when the device is granted to use more than 100mA?

Comment: If you're just concerned about the inrush from the load, you can get LDOs with soft start function that will gradually charge up any capacitors on the load. Assuming you don't need a large input capacitor on the LDO this would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AP22615 with a Riset of 12K and reach a current limit of 500mA
But as it goes with this kind of power switches, the output current is measured from the RDSon of mosfet switch.
So, there is a tolerance to factorize in. If you see the "electrical characteristics" table (page 5) see that for the Ilim parameter you can reach 1A limit typical, but the minimal is 0.75A, so we are talking about a 25% of tolerance...

You can select a part with better tolerance, or build a sample circuit and adjust the resistor value for your current limit, and even test thermally if the current limit goes off too much at different tmperatures. THe datasheet says all the parametrs are at 25C, but nothing more